# Why doesn't webpack bundled file work the same as the source file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Is there anything I did wrong in my Webpack config file?

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thian4/webpack-problem/master/webpack.prod.js

I don't know why this code would give me the following error

> React.createElement: type is invalid — expected a string

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Test extends Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Test</h1>
  }
}
```

The compiled file is in lib/test.js, why can't I import it and use it? Does it have to do with babel? I created a repo to demonstrate the problem https://github.com/thian4/webpack-problem

Comment: *'I don't know why this code would give me error'* - What error? We can't help if we don't know what the problem is. Please provide the error message.

Comment: @JoeClay this error `React.createElement: type is invalid — expected a string`